# Getting next or previous result when using Data function in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm using the charting library **d3.js** and I am looping through some data such as..

```
thresholds = plot.select('.thresholds').selectAll('.threshold').data(chart.Thresholds);
```

...and then doing something like:

```
thresholds.attr('height', function(data) {
  // How can I access the data.whatever values in here from the previous or next result in the data set?
});
```

In the example above, is there a way I can access the previous or next result in the data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_attr):

> ## selection.attr(name[, value]) <>
>
> If a value is specified, sets the attribute with the specified name to
>   the specified value on the selected elements and returns this
>   selection. If the value is a constant, all elements are given the same
>   attribute value; otherwise, if the value is a function, it is
>   evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the
>   current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group
>   (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]). The
>   function’s return value is then used to set each element’s attribute.
>   A null value will remove the specified attribute.

You can access the previous or next using the index:

```
thresholds.attr('height', function(data, i) {

   if(i>0) {
     var myvar = chart.Thresholds[i-1]
   } else {
    // Handle first case
   }

   if(i<(chart.Thresholds.length-1)) {
     var myothervar = chart.Thresholds[i+1]
   } else {
    // handle last case
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. However it would be good for whoever downvoted this to explain why this is a bad solution?